# Not able to communicate with WCF service running on separate computer using net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I am not able to communicate with another computer that is in my local area network over a net.tcp connection unless I turn the security mode off. If I set the security mode to "None", communication works fine. With the service model configuration set up as below on both ends of the wire, I get the error message "The server has rejected the client credentials".

The WCF service is being **hosted in a Windows service** on the remote computer. From what I have seen in various documentation, my configuration is set up correctly. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Wild suggestions welcomed.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ITcpService">              

            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />                  
            </security>            

            <!--Communication works if I do this
            <security mode="None" />
            -->                    
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://199.198.3.5:8520/TcpService" 
            binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ITcpService" 
            contract="TcpServiceReference.ITcpService"
            name="NetTcpBinding_ITcpService">                
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Do both machines belong to the same Windows domain?

Comment: No, both computers are not in a domain. They are both members of the same WorkGroup.

Comment: Ensure that your service is being run as an administrator account to do that you will have to open up the services window, find your service, right click and hit "Properties" from there go to "Log On" and make sure it's using an administrator account.

Comment: Jonathan - I looked at the dialog page you are referring to. I don't see any field that indicates whether or not this is an admin account and I don't see any way to start the service as an admin account. Information for "This Account" states that it is a "Network Service". I read that I can set the service to run as an admin through an entry in the manifest file. I will give that a try when I get a chance.